# Unable to use external css stylesheet in angular 9 project

Tags: css, angular, w3-css

I'm new to angular and was trying to implement something with W3 CSS. I was trying to add this css to my project. Below are the steps I have followed

1. Ran npm install --save w3-css in my project directory
2. Added `node_modules/w3-css/w3.css` in angular.json

> ```
> "styles": [
>           "src/styles.css",
>           "node_modules/w3-css/w3.css"
>         ],
> ```

After that I tried adding css classes to my component html file

```
<div class="w3-container w3-border w3-large">
    <div class="w3-left-align"><p>Left aligned text.</p></div>
    <div class="w3-right-align"><p>Right aligned text.</p></div>
</div>
```

But I couldn't see any class added.

Note: node_modules folder and angular json are in same directory.

Comment: Show how you added the css in `angular.json`

Comment: @David updated the question

Comment: `"./node_modules/w3-css/w3.css"`  try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import your css in style.css file.

```
@import "../node_modules/w3-css/w3.css";
```

Comment: Hey, that worked, but will that not cause any issue during deployment ?

Comment: And can you tell me what can be the reason it's not working even though we add it in angular.json's style array ?

Comment: no its not cause any deployment issue. may be you are not import css file in correct place at angular.json file.